# Need to display forms as per the checkboxes selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need something like this:

I had a several forms, (say form1, form2, form3 etc.. )

Respective form should be selected as per the option selected by the user..

Assume I have some checkboxes (naming as form1, form2 , form3 etc.. )

whatever the check boxes selected, respective forms should be selected one below the other dynamically..

**how can i achieve this..?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the solution in JQuery, here you go:

```
$(".formGroup").hide();
$('#chooseForm input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $("#" + $(this).val()).show();
    }
    else {
        $("#" + $(this).val()).hide();
    }   
});
```

​
A complete example:
http://jsfiddle.net/exttq/

Hope it helps!

Comment: hey thanks a lot! this is what I need actually!

But 2 problems:
a) iam unable to copy code from jsfiddle
b) How to run this jquery? anything to be added more?


please suggest me..

Comment: a) What do you mean you can't copy from jsfiddle? Are you not able to select the code and copy it?

b) To run this JQuery you need to put it inside <script></script> and put that into the page you want to have the forms.
Also you need to reference JQuery: 

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Add this before the code I presented in the fiddle.

I can't give you anymore suggestion to what you should have on your page, without knowing what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Write a Javascript or jQuery code and listen click event from the check box.

Based on the check box selected show the appropriate form.
Below sample can help...

```
 <input type="checkbox" value="form1" onclick="document.getElementById('form1-container').style.display='block'; return false;">Form 1</input>

<div id="form1-container" style="display:none"><form></form></div>
```

Comment: woww, thanks a lot Murali! BUT one thing: if I uncheck it, the form should get closed.. so how this to achive..? iam sorry i really not a good coder.. Thanx again..

Comment: one more thing: why Iam unable to see tickmark when checked?